# qmake math operation (qt increment build number)

Tags: qt, qmake

I am trying to to add build increment mechanism within .pro file.

To do so I have created a file named "version" with this content "1.1.15" *(MAJOR_VERSION.MINOR_VERSION.BUILD_NUMBER)*

Please find here my .pro content

```
MY_VERSION = "$$cat(version)"

VERSIONS = $$split(MY_VERSION, ".")

VERSION_MAJ = $$member(VERSIONS, 0)
VERSION_MIN = $$member(VERSIONS, 1)
VERSION_BUILD = $$member(VERSIONS, 2)

# VERSION_BUILD++ ??? HOW TO ???

VERSIONS = $$VERSION_MAJ $$VERSION_MIN $$VERSION_BUILD
MY_VERSION = $$join(VERSIONS, ".")

write_file(version, MY_VERSION)
```

Could someone help me on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution (not clean for me)

```
win32 {
    VERSION_BUILD = $$system("set /a $$VERSION_BUILD + 1")
} else:unix {
    VERSION_BUILD = $$system("echo $(($$VERSION_BUILD + 1))")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Qt v5.8 and up provides a `num_add` function in QMake: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmake-function-reference.html#num-add-arg1-arg2-argn